# How to Install Vue.js in Laravel 8

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8

I am using `laravel 8` and now I want install `Vue.js`. I am trying like this

1. `composer require laravel/ui`
2. `php artisan ui vue`
3. `php artisan ui vue --auth`

Comment: https://youtu.be/S9tM2fUyluk watch video here

Answer (score 61):

**UPDATE: If you want to completely avoid Inertia / Livewire (Alpine.js) scaffolding in your Laravel ^8.0 applications and use Vue instead - install [Laravel UI](https://github.com/laravel/ui), which will most likely be maintained indefinitely (scaled to practical software lifetime).**

Instructions for installing Vue (and old auth scaffolding) in your Laravel app:

1. run `composer require laravel/ui`
2. run `php artisan ui vue` for just installing Vue.
3. run `php artisan ui vue --auth` for scaffolding out the auth views.
4. run `npm install && npm run dev`

---

**How ever, if you still want to use `Vue.js` with `Livewire` scaffolding, use the following instructions.**

**IMPORTANT: Please note that `Vue.js` takes control of the DOM once installed, detaching nodes and replacing it, removing other JS listeners. So, if you are using Livewire on the same page with Vue, the `Alpine.js` that comes with `Livewire` scaffolding wont work. As a workaround you can use [Livewire VueJS support plugin.](https://github.com/livewire/vue)**

---

1. run `npm install --save vue`
2. Add the following to your resources/js/app.js:

   ```
    window.Vue = require('vue');
    Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
    });
   ```
3. Create an ExampleComponent.vue in the resources/js/components directory

   ```
   <template>
     <div>Hello World.</div>
   </template>

   <script>
     export default {
       mounted() {
         console.log("Example component mounted");
       }
     };
   </script>
   ```
4. Add `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` in the `<head>` section of your layout file (`resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`)
5. Add `id="app"` to `<body>` or main `<div>` in your layout file (`resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`)
6. Add `<example-component />` to your view
7. Run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`
8. Finally, open up the devtools, and in the console log you should see `Example component mounted`

Answer (score 23):

In laravel 8 project run following commands to install vue.js

1. run `composer require laravel/ui`
2. Install Vue `php artisan ui vue`
3. Install Vue with auth `php artisan ui vue --auth`
4. run `npm install && npm run dev`

Answer (score 7):

I wasted so much time with this and don't want people to go through the same, so I will teach you how to install Vue.js and make it work fast.

### If you want to start from scratch

replace the `LaravelProject` with your project name

```
laravel new LaravelProject
```

### Install Vue.js on your Laravel 8 application

run the following commands

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install 
npm run dev
npm run watch
```

**Now that you have installed everything you need**, go to a blade view and add the following code inside `<body></body>`

```
<div id="app">
  <example-component />
</div>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

If you did everything right you will see the following text on the rendering of your view

```
Example Component
Im an example component.
```

And in your console:
`Component mounted.`

Comment: If I do this I don't need user auth as I am doing this another way just don't run the 'php artisan ui vue --auth'  correct?

Answer (score 2):

Run a Command

```
npm install vue
```

In resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
window.Vue = require("vue/dist/vue.min");
```

And then run command

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `npm install --save vue`

Comment: ok thank you and i can use vue instead of livewire right?

Answer (score 1):

You can install vue on laravel 8 by simply running below commands to install laravel ui:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

And if you want authorizations such as login page, registartion page scaffolding then run below command from the folder where laravel project is installed:

```
php artisan ui vue
```

After running above commands run to install all dependencies and compile all style resources:

```
npm install
npm run dev
npm run watch
```

Answer (score 0):

***Setting up Vue in Laravel***

1. run `composer require laravel/ui`
2. Install Vue `php artisan ui vue`
3. if you Install Vue with  auth use `php artisan ui vue --auth`
4. add   after in page master
5. run `npm install`
6. run  `npm run dev`
7. run  `PHP artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

In existing project of Laravel 8 it's better to do this installation which gets in one line:

```
npm i -D vue@next @vue/compiler-sfc vue-loader@next
```

For your project to work correctly it's also important to check `webpack.mix.js`, it should look this way:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

As well while working with project don't forget:

```
npm run watch
```

Hope it was helpful!

Answer (score -1):

## **Install Vue + Laravel 8

`composer create-project laravel/laravel projectName --prefer-dist`

`composer require laravel/ui`

`php artisan ui vue`

`npm install`

`npm run dev`

`npm i vue-loader`

`npm install vue-router vue-axios`

`npm run dev`

*Success.*